# CSS background-image not showing up (sometimes)

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to set the background-image-property in CSS.

Here's my Code:

```css
body{
  background-color: #2C2F33 ;
  background-image: url(https://i.postimg.cc/htbpRQ6f/0f73b4070e4238fe757656ba68e24c44af64c970.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  font-family: 'Roboto', 'Arial', 'sans-serif';
  color:white;
}
```

Everything is working fine, but sometimes after starting Firefox, the Background-Image won't show up.

It will get loaded, if i'm using Strg+F5.

So the background-image isn't set properly in cache.

Does anyone know how to set it properly?

Comment: perhaps the image hosting site is rate limiting you better host image on your own server

Comment: Yes I know that. It's just for testing, because i still can't decide which Image fits the best. And of course if a "bug" like that happens, i need to fix it first.

Answer (score 0):

I shorted and update your code a little bit, It's worked on [codepen](https://codepen.io/raajkhan/pen/BamQgyy) every time. You could try it, Hope it will solve your problem.

The code:

```
body{  
  background: url("https://i.postimg.cc/htbpRQ6f/0f73b4070e4238fe757656ba68e24c44af64c970.jpg"), #2C2F33;
  background-size: cover;
  font-family: 'Roboto', 'Arial', 'sans-serif';
  color:white;
}
```

Also see from code snippet:

```css
body{  
  background: url("https://i.postimg.cc/htbpRQ6f/0f73b4070e4238fe757656ba68e24c44af64c970.jpg"), #2C2F33;
  background-size: cover;
  font-family: 'Roboto', 'Arial', 'sans-serif';
  color:white;
}
```

Comment: That's really interesting. It does work till now.
So what's the reason your CSS works, but mine not? Do you know that?

Comment: Glad to help you @Sp8iky

Comment: Hey, @Sp8iky.! I don't think it's problem with code.
Did you try with another image for the test? Sometimes site can't accessible due to ISP(Internet Service Provider) protocol. 

Make sure you try with another image/URL/file.

Comment: I have changed it now. I even uploaded the Image to my webspace and still having the same issue. That's really weird.